# bash reading multiple files with 'while read'

Tags: bash, while-loop, ifs

When I have a single textfile that I want to read line-by-line with bash, the command looks like:

```sh
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "${line}" ]];
do
    [code goes here]
done <(${filename})
```

Now, I have several files (named 1.txt through 10.txt), all of which have the same number of lines ( ~ 1600). Processing the while loop through each file individually takes a long time, is there a way to read and process everything in parallel (i.e., all 10 files will be read at the same time, but processed separately) with the while syntax? For example:

```sh
While IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "${line}" ]];
do
    [code goes here]
done <(1.txt; 2.txt; 3.txt; ...)
```

Or might there be a better method of achieving the desired multi-text processing other than creating 10 separate scripts to do this?

The overarching objective is that the files 1.txt - 10.txt consist of ~ 1600 separate ID's, in which the [code goes here] section will first:

1) read the ID line-by-line

2) based on the ID, will reference a master file which contains information about the ID, such as when the time occurred for this particular ID. Extract this time

3) Based on this extracted time information, we now build files 1 hour before, and 1 hour after at 2-minute increments. We then reference each of these 60 files, open them, and then extract a line from that file, and finally dump it to a new file.

Therefore, the process consists of opening multiple different files for referencing.

Comment: What does the "code goes here" code actually do? If it sets shell variables or otherwise modifies state in a way that needs to persist after the loop is complete, that greatly constrains your multiprocessing options.

Comment: ...also, for 1600 lines, you should have very little overhead from bash itself (not enough to make parallelization overhead worth it), which implies that it's what you're doing in the loop that's slow. If things that currently fork subshells, launch pipelines, &c. can be moved in-process, the whole problem could conceivably disappear.

Comment: You can open each file on a separate file descriptor. For file descriptors 3-9, it's fairly straightforwards. However, the documentation recommends using care for larger file descriptors, which may be used internally by the shell. There is a way to let the shell allocate an available descriptor for you, but the documentation is spotty on how to do that correctly. (Specifically, I'm not sure if you can allocate and use the descriptor in the same command, and I'm blanking how to properly close the descriptor afterwards.)

Comment: Re: "opening multiple files for referencing" -- this sounds like a job for `join`. You'll need to pre-sort the files by the join keys, but do it right and you'll have your lookups be very, very fast (and most importantly, you'll be able to do them all in one pass, instead of rereading files over and over).

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the existing script to take the filename as command-line argument.

eg. if script name is process_file.sh `$./process_file.sh <file_name>`

You could develop one more support script which has the list of files and loops and calls this script and pushes it to the background using "&"
eg.

```
declare -a arr=("1.txt" "2.txt" "3.txt")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    ./process_file.sh $i &
done
```

This might be one approach you could try and check.